# Crear cuenta en el dispositivo

Tags: swift2, xcode, cuenta-usuario, ios8

Buenas tardes estoy creando una app en swift 2 y necesito crear una cuenta de inicio de session en el dispositivo para almacenar algunos datos, alguien podría orientarme en la creación se que se utiliza una clase llamada ACAccountStore pero realmente no tengo ni idea como se utiliza y busque en la documentación y la mayoría esta medio explicado para objetive C, agradecería enormemente cualquier colaboración muchas gracias.